# Use My Own Certificate for Remote Desktop Service

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I am using Windows 10 Professional and I am wondering if I can use my own (self-signed) certificate instead of the auto-generated certificate for the Remote Desktop Service.

If I simply copy my own certificate into "Remote Desktop/Certificates" folder and remove its auto-generated one, the RDS would just stop working. Besides, Once I restart the service, it would generate a new certificate.

Would there be any measures for me to use my own certificate instead of the auto-generated one?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you imagining the benefits of doing so will be? It won't be valid either.

Comment: @ceejayoz Hi the annoying problem with the auto-generated certificate is that it would expire after half a year, which means that I always need trust new certificate. If I can use my own self-signed one, I can generate one with the life of 10 years.

Comment: Thirty seconds every six months is that much of a hardship?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the following procedure: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3042780/remote-desktop-listener-certificate-configurations-in-windows-server-2

It's for Windows Server, but I think it will work for Windows 10 too.

Comment: yes, that is the problem. For windows server, there are a lot of tutorials. However, for other windows version, even professional one, these tutorials do not work.